# Check if all pixels in a region are all empty in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have 2D canvas with things drawn to it and I want to know if all the pixels in a region (rect - x,y,w,h) are all empty/fully transparent? I know this can be done with getImageData but is there a faster way? I am writing a simple java script image packer and I wish to exclude the empty images from the final sheet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to read pixels is to use `getImageData()`, but you can speed this sort of checks up by using a different view than the default `Uint8ClampedArray`, for example `Uint32Array` which allows you to read a single pixel per iteration:

```
function isEmpty(ctx, x, y, w, h) {

    var idata = ctx.getImageData(x, y, w, h),      // needed as usual ...
        u32 = new Uint32Array(idata.data.buffer),  // reads 1x uint32 instead of 4x uint8
        i = 0, len = u32.length;

    while(i < len) if (u32[i++]) return false;     // if !== 0 return false, not empty
    return true                                    // all empty, all OK
}
```

However, this cannot be used to check for *transparency* though. Even if a pixel is fully transparent there may be color data present in the other channels. For example, this would produce an invisible pixel: `rgba(255,128,0,0)` and `isEmpty()` would report the area to be non-empty even if the pixel isn't visible.

To check those cases you'll have to check the alpha channel only, and you could simply modify the above to use an AND mask to filter out color data, or, shift the alpha channel bits over, pushing the other bits out - in either case we are after non-0 values.

As this is in little-endian (LSB) format (as on most main stream computers nowadays), the components are in the order ABGR (`0xAABBGGRR`) so we can do either:

```
u32[i] & 0xff000000
```

or use shift (sign does not matter so much in this case, but personally I prefer to use unsigned shift (>>> rather than >>) when I deal with unsigned numbers to begin with):

```
u32[i]>>>24
```

Performance wise there is very little difference, I would guess ANDing is slightly faster if anything:

**ANDing**

```
function isTransparent(ctx, x, y, w, h) {

    var idata = ctx.getImageData(x, y, w, h),       // needed as usual ...
        u32 = new Uint32Array(idata.data.buffer),   // reads 1x uint32 instead of 4x bytes
        i = 0, len = u32.length;

    while(i < len) if (u32[i++] & 0xff000000) return false; // not transparent?
    return true                                     // all transparent, all OK
}
```

**Bit-shifting**

```
function isTransparent(ctx, x, y, w, h) {

    var idata = ctx.getImageData(x, y, w, h),       // needed as usual ...
        u32 = new Uint32Array(idata.data.buffer),   // reads 1x uint32 instead of 4x bytes
        i = 0, len = u32.length;

    while(i < len) if (u32[i++]>>>24) return false; // not transparent?
    return true                                     // all transparent, all OK
}
```

**Update:**

### Speed up tricks

If you know that the data you're checking is of at least some size, lets say 2x2 pixels, you can also improve the speed by skipping every other pixel, even every other line:

```
while(i < len) if (u32[(i += 2)]>>>24) return false; // skips every 2. pixel
```

For lines, you need two iterators:

```
while(i < len) {
    var endLine = i + width, p = i;  // p in case you deal with odd widths
    while(p < endLine) if (u32[(p += 2)]>>>24) return false; // skip every 2. pixel
    i += width * 2;  // skip a line
}
```

Comment: Upvote for good answer. Given that a random sprite is likely "centered" in the image, your answer might be improved by first testing a small sample of the pixels most likely to be filled (not-transparent). In this first pass, test the centerpoint pixel of the rect and test outward in an "X" pattern. This will likely find a non-transparent pixel faster than starting with the top-left pixel.

Comment: @markE I agree with the logic provided the image is of some size, but I am not sure added complexity to a simple problem will make it run faster, ie. added iterator, boundary checks, some pattern mechanism for the X (how to check in between) etc. I think it would be better just to skip every other pixel or something like that if the data is known to be at least 2x2. But if you have a working algorithm I am happy to be proven wrong.